# OLS regression - sum of squared residuals?

Tags: self-study, least-squares

I am studying an introductory econometrics course.

$$ 
\Delta Z_t = \alpha+ \beta t + \gamma Z_{t-1} + e_t
$$

Where $e_t \sim I(0)$ with $E(e_t)=0$ and $E(e^2_t)=\sigma_e^2$

My question: is $\sigma_e^2$ just the sum of squared residuals? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

You need to distinguish between error terms, which are unobservable, and their estimators, the residuals, defined as the difference between dependent variable and fitted values.

Now, $E(e_t^2)$ is the variance of the error terms as assumed in your model equation. The assumption essentially says that the variance is taken to be constant over time.

Comment: Thank you for your response - does that mean I need to find the MSE to find the variance?

Comment: That comment seems unrelated to your previous question. You mean you want estimate the error variance? You could do that by the average of the squared residuals.